# Toggle class on div when a specific element is hovered hover (and removed)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this javascript (below) which adds/removes a class when an anchor element is hovered over.

```
a.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    cursor.classList.add('hover');
  });
  item.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    cursor.classList.remove('hover');
  });
})
```

This works - but in addition I'd like to apply a different class when two links buttons are interacted with. The classes being `.swiper-button-prev` and `.swiper-button-next`. So probably something like `hover-swiper-prev` and `hover-swiper-next` depending on which one is interacted with.

Basically when I hover over an image carousel I'd like to display different cursor styling (arrows) for each link and rotate 180 degrees (so they point left/right) when switching to prev/next 'blocks'.

For context I'm using this great bit of code to create a custom javascript mouse cursor *(it's for a portfolio/bit of fun so it's fine)*: https://codepen.io/ntenebruso/pen/QWLzVjY

Comment: I think (not sure) you want something like this [slider](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomCursors/index2.html) let me know if this helps. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about how you html looks, but here is a small snippet that might help. I added some css to demonstrate.

1. Add the class you want to add as an attribute to the html elements.

2. Grab that information to add and remove the class accordingly

```js
const a = document.querySelectorAll("a");

const cursor = document.getElementById("cursor");

a.forEach((item) => {
  const interaction = item.dataset.interaction;

  item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    cursor.classList.add(interaction);
  });
  item.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
    cursor.classList.remove(interaction);
  });
});
```

```css
.swiper-button-prev{
    background-color:green;
}

.swipper-button-next{
     background-color:yellow;
}

.hover-swiper-prev{
     background-color:orange;
}

.hover-swiper-next{
    background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
    <a href="" data-interaction="swiper-button-prev">Swipper prev</a>
    <a href="" data-interaction="swipper-button-next">Swipper next</a>
    <a href="" data-interaction="hover-swiper-prev">Hover prev</a>
    <a href="" data-interaction="hover-swiper-next">Hover next</a>

    <div style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" id="cursor">
      cursor
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank seems interesting and a good way to specify multiple different classes! So on a 'default' link, rather than targeting all `a` elements, I could just add something like `data-interaction: default-hover`? My cursor markup matches this, I've just changed the CSS a bit to create a different effect: https://codepen.io/ntenebruso/pen/QWLzVjY - then I have a slideshow with two links `.swiper-button-prev` and `.swiper-button-next`

Comment: This seems to work but I'm not sure if there's more efficient way of writing it? https://codepen.io/moy/pen/YzYPRvq - this actually works pretty smooth on CodePen but locally the cursor seems to stutter a little for the first few seconds ...maybe while swiperjs kicks in?